# Sphinx can't find number string with length more that 15

Tags: full-text-search, sphinx

I have **Sphinx 0.9.9** and field with type "string". When I store in this field number with length more than 15 (i.e. `123456789123456789`), Sphinx can't find it with full equal query.

If I store in this field `qwqwwqw 123456789123456789 qqwqw` it successfully find result.

Don't have this problem with **Sphinx 2.2**.

**My config:**

```
source resource
{
    type = xmlpipe2
    ....
    xmlpipe_field = title
    ....
}
```

```
index resources
{
    source          = resource
    path            = ....
    docinfo         = extern
    mlock           = 0
    morphology = stem_enru
    min_stemming_len    = 4
    min_word_len        = 3
    charset_type        = utf-8
    charset_table       = 0..9, A..Z->a..z, _, a..z, U+410..U+42F->U+430..U+44F, U+430..U+44F, U+002D
}
```

**Xml source dump:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<sphinx:docset>

    <sphinx:schema>
        ....
        <sphinx:field name="title" attr="string"/>
        ....
    </sphinx:schema>
    <sphinx:document id="....">
        <title><![CDATA[ .... ]]></title>
    </sphinx:document>
</sphinx:docset>
```

Comment: So what's the question and why don't you use at least Sphinx 2.2 then? 0.9.9 is soooo outdated.

Comment: @ManticoreSearch just want to know, is this a bug or I can solve this problem with some settings in config.

Comment: Can you show your index config? As from "field with type "string"" it's not clear if it's a field or a string attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug. Fixed in https://github.com/sphinxsearch/sphinx/commit/92f722b71e051312822c18417702c6a75333a03e

Be aware 0.9.9 is more than 10 years old and has hundreds of other bugs. It's time to upgrade :)